# How to use array in qz ESCP print in PHP Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, printing

```
function printESCP() {
var config = getUpdatedConfig();
var cars = ['Saab','\x0A', 'Volsvo','\x0A', 'BMW'];
var printData = [{ type: 'raw', data: cars, options: { language: 'ESCP', dotDensity: 'single' } },
'\x0A', 
'\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A',
'\x1B' + '\x69', 
];
```

Above is my code which outputs `['Saab','\n', 'Volsvo','\n', 'BMW']` in my **POS-80** printer.

But for invoice purpose I need to print it like with Item code, like 1. Saab then new line then 2. Volsvo and so on. How can I print array like this?

I am using `qz.io` printing library.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do what you're describing with ESCPOS alone.  Some use HTML, but quality will suffer.

Most people write their own character padding to suit their needs.

```
function printESCP() {
    var config = getUpdatedConfig();
    var cars = ['Saab','Volvo','BMW', 'Jaguar', 'Porsche', 'Volkswagen'];

    var table = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        table += String(" " + (i+1)).slice(-2) + ". " + cars[i] + "\x0A";
    }

    var printData = [{ type: 'raw', data: table, options: { language: 'ESCP', dotDensity: 'single' } },
        '\x0A', 
        '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A',
        '\x1B' + '\x69', 
    ];
}
```

Output:

```
 1. Saab
 2. Volvo
 3. BMW
 4. Jaguar
 5. Porsche
 6. Volkswagen








 (ESC x69)
```